# cv2 rembg remove function changes the color tone of the input image. How to fix it?

Tags: python, image-processing, rembg

in this demo color is not changed : https://huggingface.co/spaces/KenjieDec/RemBG

So here my method

```
def remove_background(image_path):
    # Read the input image
    input_image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    
    # Remove the background
    output_image = remove(input_image, alpha_matting=True, alpha_matting_erode_size=10)

    output_image_pil = Image.fromarray(output_image)
    
    return output_image_pil
```

.
.
.

```
   image = remove_background(file_path)
   image.save(save_file_path)
```

here input png. it has white background

[image]

here output png. background removed but the color tone is changed

[image]

Comment: what do you mean? the jacket is black. there is no color.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz seriously you can't notice the color change?

Comment: that minor change in hue? probably due to color space information being stripped, or a default added.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's the way how `rembg` algorithm works. Sometimes it might lose the color information.

`rembg` converts the image to a binary mask and then applies that mask to the original image. This might result in some changes in the color.

- you can try to use different background removal methods such as the `GrabCut` algorithm from `opencv`.
- try to adjust parameters of `rembg` such as `threshold`, `radius`, and `scale`.
- use the `split` function to separate the image into its color channels. Then you can adjust the color values of each channel individually. In the end, you can merge it back.
- after removing the background apply the mask to the original image with the `bitwise_and` function and then apply histogram equalization to adjust the color tone with `cvtColor` and `equalizeHist`.

Last but not least, try to look for other alternatives.

Comment: but in this demo color is not changed - https://huggingface.co/spaces/KenjieDec/RemBG